# Ionic v4 jasmine unit tests with ion-input

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, ionic4

I try to test a template driven form in Ionic v4.
But I can`t find a way to get the input element in the ion-input element.
This is what I tried:
login-register.page:

```
import { GroupsService } from './../../services/groups.service';
import { AuthenticateService, RegisterLoginReturnMessage } from './../../services/authenticate.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { addslashes } from './../../helpers';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/services/storage.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-register',
    templateUrl: './login-register.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login-register.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginRegisterPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('loginRegisterForm', { static: true })loginRegisterForm: NgForm;

    navParams: any;
    email: string;
    userName = 'blafasel';
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    password: string;
    passwordreset: string;
    loading = false;
    emailRegExpr = '[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,}';
    gdprChecked = false;

    private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticateService: AuthenticateService,
        public alertController: AlertController,
        public translateService: TranslateService,
        private location: Location,
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private groupsService: GroupsService,
        private toastController: ToastController,
        private fcm: FCM,
        private storageService: StorageService
    ) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
                console.log('if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)');
                this.navParams = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
                console.log(this.navParams);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        console.log('login is entered');
    }

    submitForm(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        console.log('submitform');
        if (this.navParams.mode === 'register') {
            this.authenticateService
                .registerUserAndGetMail(this.userName, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName)
                .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
                .subscribe(
                    (response: RegisterLoginReturnMessage) => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        if (response.valid === true) {
                            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
                            this.presentAlert('success', 'registerSuccess');
                        } else {
                            this.presentAlert('error', response.message[0], response.message[1] ? response.message[1] : '');
                        }
                        console.log('response:', response);
                    },
                    (error: RegisterLoginReturnMessage) => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.presentAlert('error', error.message[0], error.message[1] ? error.message[1] : '');
                        console.log('error bla:', error);
                    }
                );
        }

        if (this.navParams.mode === 'login') {
            this.authenticateService
                .getUserToken(this.userName, addslashes(this.password))
                .then((response: RegisterLoginReturnMessage) => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    // this.location.back();
                    // this.presentAlert('success', response.message[0], response.message[1] ? response.message[1] : '');
                    this.presentToast('success', response.message[0], response.message[1] ? response.message[1] : '');
                    // Fetch Groups from backend
                    this.groupsService.fetchUserData().then(data => {
                        console.log('promise all data:', data);
                        this.fcm
                            .subscribeToTopic(data[2].id)
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log('succesfullysubscribe:', data[2].id);
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.error('error subscription:', err);
                            });
                    });

                    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
                    console.log('response:', response);
                })
                .catch((error: RegisterLoginReturnMessage) => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    if (error.status === 0) {
                        this.presentAlert('error', 'wrongConnectionWp');
                    } else if (error.status === 403) {
                        this.presentAlert('error', 'wrongLoginData');
                    } else {
                        this.presentAlert('error', error.status.toString(), error.statusText);
                    }
                    console.log('error bla:', error);
                });
        }

        if (this.navParams.mode === 'passwordReset') {
            this.authenticateService
                .resetPassword(this.passwordreset)
                .then(response => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.presentAlert('success', response.message);
                    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.presentAlert('error', error.message[0]);
                    console.log('error in reseet pass catch', error);
                });
        }
    }

    presentAlert(header: string, message: string, messageTwo?: string): void {
        this.translateService.get([header, message, messageTwo ? messageTwo : '', 'OK']).subscribe(async (res: string[]) => {
            const newAlert = await this.alertController.create({
                header: res[header],
                message: messageTwo ? res[message] + res[messageTwo] : res[message],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'OK',
                        handler: () => {
                            console.log('ok pressed');
                        },
                    },
                ],
            });
            await newAlert.present();
        });
    }

    async presentToast(title: string, message: string, message2: string = '', duration?: number): Promise<void> {
        this.translateService.get([title, message, message2, 'OK']).subscribe(async (res: string[]) => {
            const toast = await this.toastController.create({
                header: res[title],
                message: message2 ? `${res[message]}<br>${res[message2]}` : `${res[message]}`,
                position: 'bottom',
                duration: duration ? duration : 3000,
                showCloseButton: true,
            });
            toast.present();
        });
    }

    showPassword(passwordInput) {
        passwordInput.type = passwordInput.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    }

    gotToGdpr() {
        const bla = this.translateService.currentLang;
        console.log('gotogdpr clkicked:', this.translateService.currentLang);
        const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
                postId:
                    this.translateService.currentLang === 'de' ||
                    this.translateService.currentLang === 'de-AT' ||
                    this.translateService.currentLang === 'de-CH' ||
                    this.translateService.currentLang === 'de-DE' ||
                    this.translateService.currentLang === 'de-LI'
                        ? this.storageService.appData.gdprId.de
                        : this.storageService.appData.gdprId.en,
            },
        };

        this.router.navigateByUrl('posts', navigationExtras);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // For unsubscribing all Subscriptions
        console.log('ngOnDestory');
        this.unsubscribe.next();
        this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

login-register.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button text="{{ 'back' | translate }}"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'login'">{{ 'login' | translate }}</ion-title>
        <ion-title *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">{{ 'register' | translate }}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <form #loginRegisterForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
        <ion-list inset>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                <ion-input
                    [placeholder]="'email' | translate"
                    name="email"
                    id="emailField"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="email"
                    [pattern]="emailRegExpr"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                <ion-input
                    [placeholder]="'username' | translate"
                    name="userName"
                    id="userNameField"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="userName"
                    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,30}"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <div class="username-message" item-content *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                {{ 'usernameRestrictions' | translate }}
            </div>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                <ion-input
                    [placeholder]="'firstName' | translate"
                    name="firstName"
                    id="firstNameField"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="firstName"
                    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]{1,100}"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                <ion-input
                    [placeholder]="'lastName' | translate"
                    name="lastName"
                    id="userNameField"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="lastName"
                    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]{1,100}"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'login'">
                <ion-input
                    [placeholder]="'username' | translate"
                    name="userName"
                    id="userNameField"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="userName"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'login'">
                <ion-input
                    #passwordInput
                    [placeholder]="'password' | translate"
                    name="password"
                    id="passwordField"
                    type="password"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="password"
                ></ion-input>
                <ion-icon
                    *ngIf="passwordInput.type === 'password'"
                    slot="end"
                    name="eye"
                    (click)="showPassword(passwordInput)"
                    style="font-size: 1.7rem;z-index:10"
                ></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon
                    *ngIf="passwordInput.type == 'text'"
                    slot="end"
                    name="eye-off"
                    (click)="showPassword(passwordInput)"
                    style="font-size: 1.7rem;z-index:10"
                ></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'passwordReset'">
                <ion-input name="passwordreset" id="passwordreset" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="passwordreset"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <div class="username-message" item-content *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'passwordReset'">
                {{ 'passwordReset' | translate }}
            </div>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                <a (click)="gotToGdpr()">{{ 'privacyPolicyLink' | translate }}</a>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item lines="inset" *ngIf="navParams.mode === 'register'">
                {{ 'gdprHint' | translate }}
                <ion-checkbox pattern="true" name="gdprChecked" slot="end" [(ngModel)]="gdprChecked"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-button size="full" color="tertiary" type="submit" [disabled]="!loginRegisterForm.form.valid">{{
                    'submit' | translate
                }}</ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </form>
    <ion-spinner *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-large spinner-center" color="secondary"></ion-spinner>
</ion-content>
```

login-register.page.spec.ts:

```
import { AuthenticateService } from './../../services/authenticate.service';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginRegisterPage } from './login-register.page';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { createTranslateLoader } from 'src/app/app.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import { FCMMock } from 'src/mocks/fcmMock';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// test environment
const testModuleConfig = () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [LoginRegisterPage],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        providers: [{ provide: FCM, useClass: FCMMock }, AuthenticateService],
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                    deps: [HttpClient],
                },
            }),
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
            IonicModule.forRoot(),
            IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
            HttpClientModule,
        ],
    }).compileComponents();
};

describe('LoginRegisterPage', () => {
    let component: LoginRegisterPage;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginRegisterPage>;
    let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;
    let service: AuthenticateService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        testModuleConfig();
    }));

    beforeEach(inject([AuthenticateService], (s) => {
        service = s;
        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        spyOn(router, 'getCurrentNavigation').and.returnValue({ extras: { state: { mode: 'login' } } });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginRegisterPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should be navparams login', () => {
        expect(component.navParams).toEqual({ mode: 'login' });
    });

    it('form invalid when empty', () => {
        console.log('component.loginRegisterForm.form', component.loginRegisterForm.form);
        expect(component.loginRegisterForm.form.valid).toBeFalsy();
      });

    it('should contain the correct title', () => {
        // component.title = 'Test';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#userNameField');
        const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#userNameField input'));
        console.log('element+++++++++++++++++', element);
        console.log('element+++++++++.textContent++++++++', element.textContent);
        const inputs = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'));
        console.log('first input element+++++++++++++++++', inputs[0]);
        // expect(element.i).toEqual('blafasel');
    });

    it('test function should return bla', () => {
        expect(service.testTestFunction()).toBe('bla');
    });
});
```

The
console.log('element+++++++++++++++++', element);
gives null. But the ion-input element is there with
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#userNameField'));

Can somebody help me here to make the input element available in the tests?

Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) angular decorator to get a reference to the ionic input element into a class instance variable.

For example, in your sample code:

```
<ion-input
  #emailField
  [placeholder]="'email' | translate"
  name="email"
  id="emailField"
  type="text"
  required
  [(ngModel)]="email"
  [pattern]="emailRegExpr"></ion-input>
```

In `LoginRegisterPage`, you can declare a member as:

```
  @ViewChild('emailField', {static: false}) emailField: IonInput;
```

You can then access the control's angular component methods directly from the `emailField` member variable.

HTH.